# replace two or three letters in a string with a word

Tags: android, string, split, trim

I want to do an android app that takes an input from a user and checks the string incase it has two letters "ab" or "sd" or "etc", the app should replace the letters "ab" with another string. I tried to use split function, but it does not work. For example, "To improve your chances, here ar", I want the code when it sees "ar", it will replace it with "are".

Comment: once the user type "ar" and space, the code should replace it with "are"

Comment: In other words, I want to replace a substring in a string to another one when a user makes space.

Comment: like google keyboard???

Comment: yes. where can I find how the code it